# Use Data of 1 table into another one dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table category_code having data like

```
SELECT Item, Code, Prefix from category_codes
    Item         Code  Prefix
    Bangles      BL    BL
    Chains       CH    CH
    Ear rings    ER    ER
    Sets         Set   ST
    Rings        RING  RG
    Yellow GOld  YG    YG........
```

I have another table item_categories having data like

```
select code,name  from item_categories
code            name
AQ.TM.PN        AQ.TM.PN
BL.YG.CH.ME.PN  BL.YG.CH.ME.PN
BS.CZ.ST.YG.PN  BS.CZ.ST.YG.PN
CR.YG           CR.YG.......
```

i want to update item_categories.name column corresponding to category_code.item column like

```
code               name
BL.YG.CH.ME.PN     Bangles.Yellow Gold.Chains.. . . .
```

Please suggest good solution for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that your data model is flawed. Your first table shows items with their codes. Your second table, though, shows strings with combinations of codes, but there is nothing to guarantee that these strings are properly formatted or that all codes in a string are valid codes. You should have a table with one row per combination and code instead. This would guarantee consistent data and you can get the combined codes and the combined names with `STRING_AGG` easily.

Answer (score 2):

First, split the code into several rows, join with the category code and then, concat the result to update the table.

Here an example, based on the data you gave

```
create table #category_code (item varchar(max), code varchar(max), prefix varchar(max));
create table #item_categories (code varchar(max), name varchar(max));
    
insert into #category_code (item, code, prefix) values ('Bangles','BL','BL'),('Chains','CH','CH'),('Ear rings','ER','ER'), ('Sets','Set','ST'),('Rings','RING','RG'), ('Yellow gold','YG','YG');    
insert into #item_categories (code, name) values ('AQ.TM,PN','AQ.TM.PN'),('BL.YG.CH.ME.PN','BL.YG.CH.ME.PN'),('BS.CZ.ST.YG.PN','BS.CZ.ST.YG.PN')

 
;with splitted as (  -- split the codes into individual code
    select row_number() over  (partition by ic.code order by ic.code)  as id, ic.code, x.value, cc.item
    from #item_categories ic
    outer apply string_split(ic.code, '.') x   -- SQL Server 2016+, otherwise, use another method to split the data
    left join #category_code cc on cc.code = x.value -- some values are missing in you example, but can use an inner join
)

, joined as ( -- then joined them to concat the name
    select id, convert(varchar(max),code) as code, convert(varchar(max),coalesce(item + ',','')) as Item
    from splitted
    where id = 1
    union all
    select s.id, convert(varchar(max), s.code),  convert(varchar(max), j.item  + coalesce(s.item + ',',''))
    from splitted s
    inner join joined j on j.id = s.id - 1 and j.code = s.code 
)
update #item_categories 
    set name = substring (j.item ,1,case when len(j.item) > 1 then len(j.item)-1 else 0 end)
output deleted.name, inserted.name
from #item_categories i
inner join joined j on j.code = i.code
inner join (select code, max(id)maxid from joined group by code) mj on mj.code = j.code and mj.maxid = j.id
```